# OpenVPN server, how to block clients without redirect-gateway

Tags: openvpn, redirect, gateway

is there a way not to connects a clients without redirect-gateway option? For example if the client ignore this directive with https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway.

Comment: What exactly do you want to prevent? Granting access to openvpn server and, at the same time, filtering access to all other destinations? Other? Please, give details.

Comment: I'd like to block all the clients, who do not redirect all the traffic traffic through the vpn. I'm using openvpn to control users activity in the office, i want that all the clients traffic while they are at work goes through the openvpn. I'v pushed redirect-gateway directive with a server to the clients, but i know that the client can pass this directive and while staying connected to the VPN sending some traffic beside openvpn. I'm finding the way to prevent it. Thanks.

Comment: Are clients and server connected to the same LAN? Or they reach each other via the Internet? What's the Internet connection you've at work (does it provide a router and/or a firewall you can deal with)? Will clients be able to move from one place to another ('cause, for example, they are mainly notebooks)? The answer to the first two questions are needed to correctly address your problem

Comment: We are all connected to the internet with the same cable modem. There are some access rules in the configuration of this modem.

Comment: So, can we rephrase your question as: *"How can I 'monitor' network traffic originating/destinated from/to our PCs, in our office network, where all of the PC are connected in a single LAN? I want to be able to monitor **all** their Internet traffic. I'm trying some OpenVPN based approach, but I'm experiencing some problems. Also, please note that our current gateway is a single cable-modem."*. Please let me know if this is correct, or not.

Comment: yes this is correct